# How does one change the canonical repo for a GitHub project?

Tags: github

[schacon](https://github.com/schacon) created a project on GitHub called ["showoff"](https://github.com/schacon/showoff). Later, [puppetlabs](https://github.com/puppetlabs) created [a fork](https://github.com/puppetlabs/showoff). Eventually, [schacon](https://github.com/schacon) made [puppetlabs](https://github.com/puppetlabs) the official maintainers.

If you look at the repos now, they show that `schacon`'s repo is a fork of `puppetlabs`' repo. In other words, **the fork is shown as the original and vice versa**.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

This can only be done by sending a request directly to [GitHub Support](https://github.com/contact).

It's not a normal procedure that accounts can do themselves and requires GitHub to change the designation.

It's a different step compared to [transferring a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/how-to-transfer-a-repository) which you can do yourself if you have the correct permissions.

Comment: I wonder if you could do it yourself by renaming each repo, swapping ownership, and restoring the original names, so that the original owner ends up owning the fork and vice versa.

Comment: That the "forked from" text that shows up is something only GitHub will be able to turn on or off for you. There are times, like when the parent is deleted, where it will remove that "forked from" text, but on the whole, not something users would be able to change themselves